# How to add AJAX in a custom PHP function using Google sheets API

Tags: shortcode, ajax, api

I have followed a [website link](https://www.wp-tweaks.com/display-a-single-cell-from-google-sheets-wordpress/) to fetch data from a SINGLE CELL of a Google sheet to a shortcode.

And I am using that shortcode into the [COUNTER widget in Elementor](https://elementor.com/help/counter-widget/) to achieve counting animation while fetching the fresh data from that cell of the Google sheet which updates itself after every 1 minute.

The thing I want to implement is to keep the counter "running" like the Google sheet's cell is updating (refreshes once in a minute).

The counter does not change its figure even when I reload the page. But changes the figure if I reload after like half an hour or so. But I don't want the users to reload the page to see the updated figure. I want the counter to update itself (whenever the sheet cell value changes) while the user is on the page.

PHP function I am using:

```
function sheet_value_shortcode($atts)
{
    $API = '[Insert API Key Here]';
    $google_spreadsheet_ID = '[Insert Google Spreadsheet ID Here]';
    $api_key = esc_attr($API);

    $location = $atts['location'];

    $get_cell = new WP_Http();
    $cell_url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$google_spreadsheet_ID/values/$location?&key=$api_key";
    $cell_response = $get_cell->get($cell_url);
    $json_body = json_decode($cell_response['body'], true);
    $cell_value = $json_body['values'][0][0];
    return $cell_value;
}
add_shortcode('get_sheet_value', 'sheet_value_shortcode');
```

Comment: to do this you would need to run javascript on the frontend to repeatedly fetch this data via AJAX. Also the `esc_attr` part of the code does not make sense, `esc_attr` is for escaping attributes on output e.g. `echo '<span id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '">'`

Comment: Note that any answer you get here probably won't work for you because of the counter widget, or would be broken because of the counter widget. You would need to abandon the Elementor counter widget, or seek Elementor specific help in an Elementor community, 3rd party theme/plugin/product dev support is off-topic here

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for your input :)